# How do I fix a fatal error at installation?

Tags: system-installation, bootloader

I tried reinstalling 12.04LTS x64 to my Laptop and the grub boot loader is giving me a fatal error at installation.

```
Error: Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed
```

Comment: Did you try reinstalling?

Comment: I have tried over and over to reinstall the OS from my LIve USb but I keep getting this error.

Comment: Try installing Ubuntu 13.04. Does that work?

Comment: I have at this point, Tried 12.04 LTS, 13,04, 2 Different Live USBs, 2 downloads of the 12.04, and 2 different Live USB creation methods. Unetbootin and DD.

Comment: Can you provide make and model of your laptop? Also rather than go straight to install select Try ubuntu, open a terminal with CTRL-ALT-T and add the output of `fdisk -l` to your question. Thank you.